# How do you create a common method within a class that inherited from unittest.TestCase?

Tags: python

Let's say I have the following code:

`file1.py`

```
class TestA(unittest.TestCase)
   def test_something(self):
     results = something()
     self.common_verify_method(results)

   def common_verify_method(self, results)
       expected = expected_method()
       self.assertEqual(results, expected)  # this uses self.assertEqual
```

`file2.py`

```
Class TestB(unittest.TestCase):
    def my_other_code(self):
        results = do_something()
        # Here I would like to call common_verify_method() from file1.py
```

In `file2.py`, I would like to call call `common_verify_method()` from `file1.py`. One way I can call do this by inhereting from `TestA` in  `TestB`. The following works OK:

```
Class TestMyOtherCode(TestA)
    def my_other_code(self):
        results = do_something()
        self.common_verify_method(results)
```

If I don't want to inherent from `TestA`, how can I call `common_verify_method()`. If I use composition, I get the following error:

```
Class TestMyOtherCode(unittest.TestCase)
    def my_other_code(self):
        results = do_something()
        test_a = TestA()
        test_a.common_verify_method(results)

ValueError: no such test method in <class 'tests.file1.TestA'>: runTest
```

Comment: Question is still unclear. can you explain it more? Both of your classes are inheriting from `unittest.TestCase`

Comment: In `file2.py`, I would like to call `call common_verify_method()` from `file1.py`. How can I accomplish this without directly inheriting from TestA. If you instantiate TestA in TestB, you will get an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `TestB` inheriting from `TestA`, or the other way round, they should both inherit from a common base class:

```
class CommonBase(unittest.TestCase)
   def common_verify_method(self, results)
       expected = expected_method()
       self.assertEqual(results, expected)  # this uses self.assertEqual

class TestA(CommonBase):
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code to get the expected result in both classes (i.e) TestA & TestMyOtherCode. I created two python files let's say Sample1 & Sample2.

**Here is a code**

**Sample1.py**

```
import unittest

class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_something(self):
     results = 5
     self.common_verify_method(results)

   def common_verify_method(self, results):
       expected = 5
       self.assertEqual(results, expected)
```

**Sample2.py**

```
from Sample1 import TestA
import unittest

class TestMyOtherCode(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self):
        self.other = TestA

    def my_other_code(self):
        results = 5
        self.other.common_verify_method(results)
```

I used **Composition** method in python. It works fine and gave expected result.

Try it...